# How to replace startActivityForResult with ActivityResultLauncher but still include options Bundle?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

`startActivityForResult(intent: Intent!, options: Bundle?)` has been deprecated. I am trying to replace with `ActivityResultLauncher` but I need to pass the `options`. How can I do this with the new method? Below is an example of the original (now deprecated) method that would open the Contacts menu and then do one of two things in the switch based on the value of `code`:

```
...
val code = contactType //can be either 1 or 2
val contactsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
contactsIntent.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
startActivityForResult(contactsIntent, code)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when(requestCode) {
            1 -> { //Do something
            }
            2 -> { //Do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to convert the above to use `ActivityResultLauncher` but I haven't figured out how to pass the value of `code` to it. Below is what I have so far:

```
val code = contactType //can be either 1 or 2
val contactsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
contactsIntent.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
contactLauncher.launch(contactsIntent) //or maybe contactLauncher.launch(contactsIntent, code)?

private val contactLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when(??? requestCode ???) {
            1 -> { //Do something
            }
            2 -> { //Do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is that you would use two separate `ActivityResultLauncher` objects, one for each scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, you'll need to create two separate ActivityResultLauncher objects, one for each case.

IMO, this is exactly what Google was trying to solve, having a cluttered "onActivityResult" function, as well as having to deal with requestCodes. Right now, this is more similar to an OnClickListener kind of callback.

They did the same with other parts of Android, like requesting app permissions. The requestCode is now handled internally.

Comment: And before you needed one int, and now 3 objects, its exactly what are they doing - I call it overengineering, IMHO.

Comment: I call it separation of concerns, but I guess it depends on how you use them.

Answer (score 1):

An overloaded version of 'launch()' allows you to pass an 'ActivityOptionsCompat' in addition to the input.

@see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher